# FFmpeg send stream on a web server

Tags: ffmpeg, udp

For stream my screen, i used :

```
ffmpeg -s 1920x1080 -f X11grab -i :0.0+0,0 -codec:v libvpx -b:v 4M -b:a libvorbis -crf 20 capture.webm
```

This command save the stream in a file : capture.webm.

But now, I want send stream on a udp server. So i make this command :

```
ffmpeg -s 1920x1080 -f X11grab -i :0.0+0,0 -codec:v libvpx -b:v 4M -b:a libvorbis -crf 20 -f webm udp://192.168.232.2:8080
```

But it doesn't run.

Comment: Show the complete console output from the command that doesn't run.

Comment: Ty for response. The command run, but on my udp server, i receive bad bytes. The function recvfrom return often -1

Answer (score 1):

To send a stream to a server instead of

```
-f webm udp://192.168.232.2:8080
```

use

```
-f rtp rtp://192.168.232.2:32200
```

where 32200 is some not used port

To play it from there you can use:

```
1. ffplay with sdp
2. Set up WebRTC with Janus
3. Publish video in flv format to rtmp server and play it using Flash:
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp -loglevel repeat+info -i source.sdp -flags +global_header -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/mystream/mystream1
```

where source.sdp(comes from output from ffmpeg -s 1920x1080 -f X11grab -i :0.0+0,0 -codec:v libvpx -b:v 4M -b:a libvorbis -crf 20 -f webm udp://192.168.232.2:32200)

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.1.1
s=No Name
c=IN IP4 192.168.232.2
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 57.71.100
m=video 32200 ....
```

If you don't want to build media server and viewing logic in the browser you can either send stream from your screen to any of Media Servers for example Wowza or Facebook Live(according to instructions)